# #define not recognised by library

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am building a library project and a test project to test this library on. I want the user (A.K.A. the test project) to be able to define some things for the library, but the #define is not recognized in my library and just throws an error.

**I am building the library project as static library, the build order is that the library builds first and then the test project since the project is dependent on the library.

In the test project I want the user to be able to define like this (before the include):

```
#define PUT_DEFINE_HERE
```

In the library I just check with:

```
#ifdef PUT_DEFINE_HERE
//Do some stuff
#endif
```

As stated before the library does not see the #define defined by the user. I tried some stuff with the build order but no luck so far, any ideas?

Comment: So you first build the library, and then expect the define in some unrelated user build to affect it when linking, correct?

Comment: Is "Do some studd" inside a header file (.h) or a .cpp file?

Comment: Correct I first build the lib, but yes it is inside the header file.

Comment: What **errors** do you get?...

Comment: The error is only a symptom of the problem it is not important, it is caused because of the fact it does not recognize the #define

Comment: Preprocessor instructions are pre-compile-time. The compiler doesn't even look at the disabled branches, so if your library is already built with specific settings, you can't do much here... If you want the user code to be able to affect that, put your `#if` switches to .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the library to "accept" a user `#define`, the check on the presence of `PUT_DEFINE_HERE`

```
#ifdef PUT_DEFINE_HERE
//Do some stuff
#endif
```

must be done at the header lever, and only there

Secondly, the user project which includes the library header must `#define PUT_DEFINE_HERE` *before* including the library header.

Alternatively, if such a setting is incompatible with the library design, then the `#define` must be added at compile time, e.g.:

```
gcc -DPUT_DEFINE_HERE ...
```

In this case, be sure to compile every source with `-DPUT_DEFINE_HERE`, when relevant.

Comment: Yea I was afraid of that, is there a way around it so the presence is validated at run time?

Comment: ```#define```s are processed by the preprocessor, hence by definition they cannot be checked at runtime. That said, you could inside the code store in a variable whether ```PUT_DEFINE_HERE``` was defined at compile time. Something like ```#ifdef PUT_DEFINE_HERE bool is_defined=true #else bool is_defined=false #endif```